# Telling 'Find' to exclude core system directories ("! -name -'*.svn'" doesn't work)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

I'm trying to do a "search and destroy" on the copy of GHC that's currently installed on my system (so I can reinstall a new version).  As part of locating any residual files which may be left over, I'm trying to do a manual search for any and all directories that contain "ghc".

I'm using the following search command but it's printing out a whole bunch of useless stuff, namely lists of directories which don't match my search term and whicy appear to be core system directories.

I thought that excluding '*.svn' might be the trick but clearly it's not working.

Any suggestions as to how I can suppress these files from search results?

I'm using zsh on Ubuntu 14.04

```
~ ❯❯❯ find / -type d -iname "ghc" ! -iwholename '*.svn'                       ⏎
find: `/media/sf_dchaudh': Permission denied
find: `/usr/share/doc/google-chrome-stable': Permission denied
find: `/sys/kernel/debug': Permission denied
find: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs': Permission denied
find: `/var/spool/cups': Permission denied
find: `/var/cache/ldconfig': Permission denied
find: `/var/cache/system-tools-backends/backup': Permission denied
find: `/var/cache/lightdm/dmrc': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/sudo': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/polkit-1': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/udisks2': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/lightdm': Permission denied
find: `/var/log/cups': Permission denied
find: `/var/tmp/kdecache-kdm': Permission denied
find: `/var/tmp/kdecache-dc': Permission denied
find: `/home/dchaudh/.gvfs': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just figured it out.  This is what I was looking for, in case helpful for others:

```
find / -iname "*ghc" -print 2>/dev/null
```

(Others should feel free to post a better answer if they have one.  I'll obv not accept my own answer..."